# code igniter queries: how to build this query

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I am attempting to build a query using code igniter's active records class that looks like this:

`SELECT * from contacts where account = 1 and (fname like 'k%' or lname like 'k%')`

however I am not sure how to use the functions to do this.

and ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use the like query

```
$this->db->like('title', 'match');

// Produces: WHERE title LIKE '%match%'
```

And  or_like

```
$this->db->like('title', 'match');
$this->db->or_like('body', $match);
```

Comment: +1 for the like function that Codeigniter's Active Record provides. It's so much easier than writing likes in an select where statement.

Answer (score 3):

```
$this->db->where('account', '1');
$this->db->where(' (fname LIKE "k%" OR lname LIKE "k%" ) ');
$query = $this->db->get('contacts');
```

Then just deal with `$query` like a normal Codeigniter database result.

Answer (score 0):

Yo can allways run it as a normal query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * from contacts where account = 1 and (fname like ? or lname like ?)";
$query = $this->db->query($sql, array( $like1, $like2));
```

I use more often this than the active record class as I'm keen in writing sql statements.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using normal query, you can use the suggestion from the ellislab forum https://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/185983/
Instead of using

```
$this->db->like('location', $your_string);
```

use:

```
$this->db->where('location LIKE', '%'.$your_string.'%');
```

and **or_where** instead of **or_like**.

Answer (score 0):

You can use query grouping from CI 3.0

```
$this->db->select('*')->from('contacts ')
    ->group_start()
            ->like('fname', 'k', 'after');
            ->or_like('lname', 'k', 'after'); 
    ->group_end()
    ->where('account', 1)
->get();
```